# ¿Por qué la vista no ejecuta repaint() en update()?

Tags: java

Tengo problemas, al pintar una vista, siguiendo el patrón MVC.

El problema es que cuando el modelo indica que el objeto observable ha cambiado, se ejecuta la actualización de la vista, pero al llamar al repaint() no ejecuta su contenido. Lo que quiero pintar es una imagen, el problema puede ser que la clase extiende la vista, no sea apropiada (Canvas).

Al depurar, lo que sucede es que el modelo notifica a la vista que el objeto se ha modificado, luego ejecuta el método update (), pero no ejecuta el contenido de paint ().

El modelo se modifica cuando la "anguloRotacion", en la que aumento o disminuyo, el ángulo de rotación de la imagen. Este código se encuentra dentro del método anguloRotacion (), dentro del modelo.

Si necesitáis más explicaciones o aclaraciones, por favor hacermelo saber. Realmente necesito resolver este problema.

**Controller code:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controlador;

import Auxiliares.Canon;
import Auxiliares.Casilla;
import Auxiliares.ContenedorFinal;
import Vistas.*;
import Vistas.VistaCanon;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI;

/**
 *
 * @author ignacioaranguren
 */
public class Controlador extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contenedorFinal;
    private JProgressBar barra;
    private ActionListener ac;
    private Timer t;
    private int puntuacion = 0;
    private DecimalFormat timeFormatter;
    private JLabel etiquetaFin;
    private JButton finalizar;
    private Graphics2D offGraphics;
    private Image offImage;
    private Modelo modelo;
    private VistaCanon vistaCanon;
    private VistaBala vistaBala;
    private VistaCasillas vistaCasillas;
    private VistaCorazon vistaCorazon;
    private VistaHaCaidoAgua vistaHaCaidoAgua;
    private VistaSegundero vistaSegundero;
    private VistaPuntuacion vistaPuntuacion;

    public Controlador() {

        setLayout(null);
        modelo = new Modelo();
        vistaCanon = new VistaCanon(modelo);

        modelo.addObserver(vistaCanon);

        modelo.initComponents();
        timeFormatter = new DecimalFormat("00");
        etiquetaFin = new JLabel("Juego finalizado");
        etiquetaFin.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 35));
        etiquetaFin.setBounds(250, 330, 300, 100);
        etiquetaFin.setVisible(false);
        finalizar = new JButton("Menu principal");
        finalizar.setBounds(300, 410, 150, 30);
        finalizar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        finalizar.setVisible(false);
        contenedorFinal = new ContenedorFinal();
        contenedorFinal.setBackground(Color.red);
        contenedorFinal.setVisible(false);
        contenedorFinal.setBounds(0, 0, 940, 900);

        barra = new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100);
        barra.setBounds(450, 730, 200, 40);
        barra.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        barra.setUI(new BasicProgressBarUI() {
            @Override
            protected void paintDeterminate(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                int ancho = barra.getWidth();
                int alto = barra.getHeight();

                int espacioAncho = ancho;
                int espacioAlto = alto;
                barra.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 40));
                double porcentajeProgres = barra.getPercentComplete();

                espacioAncho = (int) (espacioAncho * porcentajeProgres);
                if (porcentajeProgres <= 0.25) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else if (porcentajeProgres > 0.25 && porcentajeProgres <= 0.5) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.yellow);
                } else if (porcentajeProgres > 0.5 && porcentajeProgres <= 0.75) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.orange);
                } else {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
                }
                Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, espacioAncho, espacioAlto);
                g2d.fill(rec1);
            }

        });   
        ac = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                modelo.BarraProgreso();
            }

        };

        modelo.setBarra(barra);
        modelo.setBotonFinalizar(finalizar);
        modelo.setContenedorFinal(contenedorFinal);
        modelo.setEtiquetaFin(etiquetaFin);
        modelo.setTimerFormater(timeFormatter);

        t = new Timer(35, ac);
        t.start();

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evento) {
                switch (evento.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        modelo.anguloRotacion(1);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        modelo.anguloRotacion(2);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
                        modelo.anguloRotacion(3);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:         
                        repaint();
                        modelo.salirJuego(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Volver al menú principal?", "Juego", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION));
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_H:
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "-Pulsa las teclas izquierda y derecha para mover el cañón.\n-Selecciona una "
                                + "intensidad mediante la barra de fuerza:\n   -Rojo = Disparar fuerte.\n   -Amarillo = disparar medio fuerte"
                                + ". \n   -Verde = disparar suave.\n-Pulsa Enter para disparar. \n-Durante el disparo puedes modificar su trayectoria mediante la teclas izquierda y derecha."
                                + "\n-La puntuación: \n   -Los cangrejos (+1). \n   -Los tesoros (+2). \n   -Las botellas de ron (-1) vidas.", "Cómo jugar", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                        break;
                }
                requestFocus();
            }    
        });

        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                close();
            }
        });

        setSize(940, 900);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        add(finalizar);
        add(etiquetaFin);
        setResizable(false);
        add(contenedorFinal);
        add(barra);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Image fondo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/fondo.jpeg")).getImage();
        g2d.drawImage(fondo, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Marker Felt", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.drawString("Cómo jugar, Pulsa H", 710, 330);
        g2d.drawString("Pulsa ESC para salir", 710, 380);      
        Image img2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/fondoMapa.png")).getImage();
        g2d.drawImage(img2, 30, 30, this);
    }

    private void close() {
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "¿Volver al menú principal?",
                "Juego", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }    

}
```

**Model manipulation:**

```
   package controlador;

import Auxiliares.Canon;
import Auxiliares.Casilla;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author ignacio
 */
public class Modelo extends Observable {

    private double anguloRotacion, anguloMin, anguloMax;
    private boolean teclaPresionada, flag, flagBala, pintarCasilla, balaAgua;
    private JProgressBar barra;
    private double vX, vY, x1, x2, x1Anterior, x2Anterior, alfa, escala, i;
    private Timer animacion, timer;
    private Canon canon;
    private int progreso, x, y, puntuacion, vidas, posVidaX, contadorCasilla;
    private Casilla[][] casilla;
    private double posX[], posY[];
    private BufferedImage imgB;
    private Image img2, fondo, fondoMapa, vida, img;
    private ArrayList<Casilla> arrayCasilla;
    private JLabel etiquetaFin;
    private JButton finalizar;
    private JPanel contenedorFinal;
    private byte seconds;
    private short minutes;
    private DecimalFormat timeformater;


    public void setBarra(JProgressBar b){
        this.barra = b;
    }

    public void setEtiquetaFin(JLabel f){
        this.etiquetaFin = f;
    }

    public void setTimerFormater(DecimalFormat d){
        timeformater = d;
    }

    public void setContenedorFinal(JPanel p){
        contenedorFinal = p;
    }

    public void setBotonFinalizar(JButton b){
        this.finalizar = b;
    }


    public void initComponents(){
        seconds = 00;
        minutes = 03;

        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
                    timer.stop();
                    etiquetaFin.setVisible(true);
                    finalizar.setVisible(true);
                    contenedorFinal.setVisible(true);

                } else if (seconds > 0) {
                    seconds--;
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers();

                } else if (minutes > 0) {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 59;
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers();
                }

            }
        });
        timer.start();

        posX = new double[]{30, 79, 128.0, 177.0, 226.0, 275.0, 324.0, 373.0, 422.0, 471.0, 520.0, 569.0, 618};
        posY = new double[]{30, 83.0, 136.0, 189.0, 242.0, 295.0, 348.0, 401.0, 454.0, 507.0, 560.0, 613.0, 613};
        casilla = new Casilla[13][13];
        inicializarCasillas();
        anguloRotacion = Math.PI / 2;
        vidas = 3;
        anguloMax = 0.81986726449;
        anguloMin = anguloMax = 2.32172538679;
        teclaPresionada = false;
        flag = false;
        flagBala = false;
        pintarCasilla = false;
        balaAgua = false;
        i = 0;
        progreso = 0;
        this.canon = canon = new Canon();
        this.barra = barra;
        arrayCasilla = new ArrayList<>();
        llenarCasillas();
    }

    public void cargarImagenes() {
        try {
            img2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/fondoMapa.png")).getImage();
            fondo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/fondo.jpeg")).getImage();
            vida = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/vida.png")).getImage();
            img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/BalaCanon.png")).getImage();
            imgB = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/canon.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Modelo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public void anguloRotacion(int direccion) {
        switch (direccion) {
            case 1:
                if (anguloRotacion > anguloMin && anguloRotacion < anguloMax) {
                    anguloRotacion = anguloRotacion + 0.05;
                } else {
                    anguloRotacion = anguloRotacion - 0.05;
                }
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers();
                break;
            case 2:
                if (anguloRotacion > anguloMin && anguloRotacion < anguloMax) {
                    anguloRotacion = anguloRotacion - 0.05;
                } else {
                    anguloRotacion = anguloRotacion + 0.05;
                }
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

**View code:**

```
package Vistas;

import controlador.Modelo;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;


public class VistaCanon extends Canvas implements Observer {

    private Modelo m;

    public VistaCanon(Modelo m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.gray);
        g2d.fillRect(30, 720, 646, 122);
        AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI / 2 - m.getAnguloRotacion(), m.getImB().getWidth(this) / 2, m.getImB().getHeight(this) / 2);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
        tx.rotate(Math.PI / 2 - m.getAnguloRotacion());
        System.out.println(tx.toString());

        g2d.drawImage(op.filter(m.getImB(), null), 360, 740, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        repaint();
    }

}
```